# How to find a bijection which maps a complex number to real number?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, notation

I'm trying to map a complex number z with its length |z|=1 into the interval [0, 1).

My solving proces:
Its obvious the $|z|=1$ represents all complex numbers which lie on the circumference with the radius 1.

1. How do I write elegantly the mapping domains?
   Well, the first idea $f: a+ib \rightarrow [0, 1)$ but I have never ever seen such notation.
   In my previous problems I always had something similar to this $f: R \times R \rightarrow R$.
   I tried this as well $(|z|\cos\varphi,0)\times(0,|z|\sin\varphi), \varphi \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2})\rightarrow [0, 1)$ . But it doesn't sit right (even without $|z|$ inside) . Or its just me?

Back to finding the actual bijection:

2. From the sketch it's clear one of the bijective functions could be $f(\varphi)= cos\varphi$. Is this correct? Just asking, because this is the first problem I solved dealing with the complex numbers. Others were N, Z and R sets.

Also: Is $f(\varphi)= cos\varphi$ the only correct function or is there another? I feel like the the problem led me to this solution.

[image: picture1]

Comment: $\cos(\varphi)$ is bijective if you only consider the complex numbers of modulus $1$ of the *first quadrant*. If you consider all the complex numbers of modulus $1$, then it is not bijective.

Comment: Why can't it be $f:\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\}\to[0,1)$? For $z$ on the unit circle, $f(z):z\mapsto\arg(z)\in[0,2\pi)$ is a bijection. Can you scale this to range of $[0,1)$?

Comment: Cut the circle and flat it out straight

Comment: @ShubhamJohri That is what I was missing!

Comment: $\phi \not \in \mathbb C$.  $\phi \in \mathbb R$.  You seem to be assuming you already have a way of mapping $z\mapsto \phi=\arg(z)$.  But that's *already* a mapping from $\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|=1\} \to \mathbb R$.  Indeed $f:\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|=1\}\to [0,2\pi)$ is *already* a bijection.  Just scale it.  No need to project it to its cosine (which isn't bijective when you  get to the third and fourth quadrant).

Comment: @fleablood You are right! Didn't even thought about  being in ℂ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have misunderstood your question but if you take the angle that every complex number creates with the center and devide by 2*pi you'l get a bijection between the complex numbers with size 1 and the real numbers between 0 and 1